# Flutter: How to make such Edit text and remove the unexpected layout padding

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement this design:
[image]

i'm very beginner to flutter, and what i'm getting is this:
[image]

I don't want you guys to get me wrong, i'm not asking for someone to implement this for me.
i need guidance on how to:

1. remove the layout padding.
2. make a textview and edit text side by side look like one widget.
3. remove the space between the edit texts.
4. implement the CheckBox (i tried a row with check box and text, didn't work)
5. show a proper arrow in "Sign In" (instead of ->).

just some explanations, guidance and any documentation or tutorial that could be good for my case.

[Here is my code](https://github.com/Simouche/flutter-layouts-examples/blob/master/registration_page.dart)

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the layout padding.
2. make a textview and edit text side by side look like one widget.

Im not sure of this if your talking about inside TextFormField you can use `contentPadding` inside InputDecoration. But based on your layout design, you can separate the Label in TextFormField and create your own label text

```
Row(
 children:[
  Text("LABEL"),
  Expanded(
    child: TextFormField(),
     ) 
   ]
)
```

4.implement the CheckBox (i tried a row with check box and text, didn't work)

```
Row(
        children: [
          Checkbox(
              value: isValue,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  isValue = value;
                });
              }),
              Text("SOME TEXT"), //Read RichText widget for your design
        ],
      ),
```

For you arrow -> sign in

Try using `Icon()` widget